# Can I make a login system for use with embedded systems to login and upload data with Django?

Tags: django, web-services

I want to try make a web service where the users can post data into a database, and it also should support data posts by some system that is not used my some user. In the end it should have some type of webAPI to allow other users to make other kind of web services using whatever data it contains in the database.

But my main question is does Django have some type of shell interaction function that I can use to let embedded system to login, then to talk to my web service and post data?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a very broad question thats not really what stack is for.. To slighty awnser your second question, you can use a REST framework within django to create that kind of api interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can build a REST API using one of the packages listed here:

http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/api/